# Credenciales de Autentificacion para enviar correo desde C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un servidor donde envio y recibo mensajes, cree una app desde C# donde pueda enviar correos pero no me reconoce los credenciales que le digo, me dice que son falsas:

```
                correo = new MailMessage();
                correo.To.Add(new MailAddress(this.to));
                correo.From = new MailAddress("name.last@local.com");
                correo.Subject = subject;
                correo.Body ="";
                correo.IsBodyHtml = false;


                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("web.local.com", 443);


                using (client)
                {
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name.last@local.com", "xxxx");
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(correo);
                }
                try
                {
                    correo.Dispose();
                    MessageBox.Show("Email was successfully sent. ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error sending email. " + ex, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                }
```

No se si por ser local se usen otros puertos. El problema es que no reconoce el usuario.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: si es local usa el puerto 25

Comment: Por favor, pon el mensaje completo de error. Lo otro, 443 no suena a puerto para SMTP, seguro que es ese? SSL en SMTP usa por defecto 465, 443 puede ser otro servicio que obvio no va a reconocer esas credenciales :/

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste agregar en el bloque de client el siguiente parametro de UseDefaultCredentials.

```
            using (client)
            {
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // o true dependiendo el caso de acceso
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name.last@local.com", "xxxx");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(correo);
            }
```